# How to keep a div's height 100%?

Tags: css

I have 2 grids: one side bar and one main section. I desire to have sidebar's div height 100%.
However, the height of main section breaks that.. and I don't understand how/why that happens...

To be clear:

Page:

```
 <div class="wrap">

 <div class="section group">    

 <div class="col section_1_2">
    <div class="sideBar">sideBar</div>
 </div><!--section_1_2-->

 <div class="col section_2_2"> 
    <div class="layout">layout
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
    </div>
 </div><!--section_2_2-->    

 </div><!--section group-->   

 </div><!--wrap-->
```

Css:

```
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}

 body,html{height:100%;}

 .wrap{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }

 .sideBar{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:lightblue;
 }

 .layout{
 width:90%;
 height:auto;
 background:blue;
 margin:0 auto;
 }

 .layout span{
 width:200px;
 height:500px;
 background:yellow;
 display:block;
 clear:both;    
 }

 /* fluid grids */
 .section_1_2{
 width:20%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .section_2_2{
 width:80%;
 height:100%;
 }

 /* Grid settings*/
 .section{
 clear:both;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 height:100%;
 }
.group:before,
.group:after{
 content:"";
 display:table;
 }
.group:after{
 clear:both;
 }
.col{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 }
```

So what happens is: If I don't add these span tags(which is extra 2000px height), sidebar will appear correctly(100% height) but If I add long height content in layout it breaks the 100% height of sidebar..

So what happens here actually? What changes the height of the page or sidebar?

Please check here: http://jsfiddle.net/83noLsjv/1/

Probably this is something really simple but I can't see the solution to keep sidebar 100% height and at the same time add long content in layout...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want the sidebar to be 100% of what, exactly? And do you mean that you want it to stay on the screen when you scroll?

Comment: 100% means 100% of the window size, which the sidebar actually is. if you want the sidebar to be 100% of the document, I'm afraid you're going to need to use JS

Comment: I just want sidebar to be 100% even if the layout is 2000px.. in that exp above..it doesn't work..

Comment: @AminJafari you don't need to use javascript. You just have to write your CSS properly.

Comment: Did you even look at any of the bazillion EXISTING answers on this topic before posting this question?

Comment: yes, I have read alot..

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex care to show us how? I'm eager to learn if there's a way

Comment: @AminJafari http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/vx7pzjd6/

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex it's a workaround but that's not really it, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your position to fixed of the sidebar in css.

position:fixed

Answer (score 1):

Height is calculated differently than width - "browsers don't evaluate height at all unless the content is so long that it goes outside of the view port".

The exact problem you are having here is described in this post:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Referring to: "The problem occurs when you set a percentage height on an element who's parent elements don't have heights set. In other words, the parent elements have a default height: auto;. You are, in effect, asking the browser to calculate a height from an undefined value. Since that would equal a null-value, the result is that the browser does nothing."

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use `overflow: auto` on your main container that you want to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/vx7pzjd6/